Kotlin - Android : calling a function with parameters between {..} instead ()
setContent is a function called with parameter between {}. Where is the kotling or Android docs explaining this?
I am learning "Create your first Android app" in https://developer.android.com/, I wish to understand deeply all the kotlin language particularities and android classes. Below this code is a fragment of the setContent function
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            GreetingCardTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

-------------------------------------------

public fun ComponentActivity.setContent(
    parent: CompositionContext? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val existingComposeView = window.decorView
        .findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)
        .getChildAt(0) as? ComposeView

    if (existingComposeView != null) with(existingComposeView) {
        setParentCompositionContext(parent)
        setContent(content)
    } else ComposeView(this).apply { ......


https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-function-types-and-lambda#0 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

This is specifically covered by this section of the documentation.

I guess your question is about Trailing Lambda in Kotlin, see more from docs.
public fun ComponentActivity.setContent(
    parent: CompositionContext? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) { .... }

As you can see from the source code, setContent() signature has 2 parameters  inside a parenthesis i.e. parent and content.
It is the content parameter that is most interesting:
content: @Composable () -> Unit

content - name of the parameter

@Composable - marks a function as a Composable function for declaring UI elements

:() -> Unit - Specifies the type, in this case a Lambda type.


A lambda is an anonymous function expression, A Trailing Lambda lets you move the lambda expression out of the parentheses of a function if the lambda is the last argument.
In this case we move the content parameter out of setContent() and end up with:
setContent(parent: CompositionContext? = null){ ...}.
This is further simplified as setContent {} because parent is an optional parameter set to null and can be omitted.
Please also see this question
